# Android sign keystore

Tags: android, google-play

I have a problem. I have release application using A keystore, after that i found a bug and release the second version i sign  using the same A keystore.
But when i upload my apk in android market, they reject it, with this warning:

Market does not accept apks signed with the debug certificate. Create a new certificate that is valid for at least 50 years.
Market requires that the certificate used to sign the apk be valid until at least October 22, 2033. Create a new certificate.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message it sounds like you did the second build using the default debug certificate rather than using your own keystore.